# Generic access to DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

`ObjectContext` allows generic access to the generated Entities. `DbContext` appears to have no such support.  Accessing EF5 with a generic repository is challenging.  Let's say I want a generic mechanism to read any given entity, call it TEntity:

```
public class DataRepositoryEF5<T> where T: DbContext
{
    private ObjectContext _context;        

    public DataRepositoryEF5(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> ReadAll<TEntity>() where TEntity : class,new()
    {
        return GetObjectSet<TEntity>().AsEnumerable();
    }

    protected ObjectSet<TEntity> GetObjectSet<TEntity>() where TEntity : class,new()
    {
        ObjectSet<TEntity> result;
        result = _context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
            var context = new MyContext();            
            var repository = new DataRepositoryEF5<MyContext>(context);

            IEnumerable<Document> results = repository.GetAll<Document>();

            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", item.Description, item.Id, item.Property, item.Whatever);
            }
```

EF used to generate classes with a common base type `EntityObject`. Since that is no longer the case the best constraint I can have is `class`...

Second, because there is no equivalent of `ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<>()` I am forced to cast from `DbSet` to `ObjectSet`.

With this pattern in place I have no need for `DbContext`.  Without generics I am forced to hand code all CRUD operations.  Did I miss something? If not, is it possible to tell EF5 to generate code with `ObjectContext` instead?

Comment: have a look at this tip that I posted on codeproject a while ago
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/309753/Repository-Pattern-with-Entity-Framework-4-1-and-C

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso - Yes that article is exactly what I need! Per your example context.Set<>() is the new way to do it. I see you are also with a `class` constraint on the Entities.  If you want to post the comment as the answer I will give answer credit. –

Answer (score 13, accepted):

have a look at this [tip](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/309753/Repository-Pattern-with-Entity-Framework-4-1-and-C) that I posted a while ago

Anyway the trick is by using `context.Set<>`

```
public interface IEntity
        {
            int Id { get; set; } 
        } 

public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        private IDbContext _context;
        public Repository(IDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
          private IDbSet<TEntity> DbSet
         {
            get
            {
                return _context.Set<TEntity>();
            }
         }
          public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll() 
          {
             return DbSet.AsQueryable(); 
          }
        public void Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
             DbSet.Remove(entity);
        }
.....
```

Comment: Here's a more complete reference: https://gist.github.com/JerryNixon/915faf1e0aed75b61d1c7048c0fc0322

Answer (score 0):

This is a more up to date and complete answer.

```cs
using Library.Models;
using Library.EF;

namespace Abstractions
{
  public interface IKeyedModel
  {
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
  }

  public class GenericContext<T> : DbContext where T : class, IKeyedModel
  {
    public DbSet<T> Items { get; set; } = default!;
  }

  public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IKeyedModel
  {
    public GenericContext<T> Context() => new GenericContext<T>();

    public T Select(int id) => Context().Items.Single(x => x.Id == id);

    public IQueryable<T> Select() => Context().Items;

    public void Insert(T item)
    {
      var context = Context();
      context.Items.Add(item);
      context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Update(T item)
    {
      var context = Context();
      context.Items.Attach(item);
      context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
      var context = Context();
      var item = context.Items.Single(x => x.Id == id);
      context.Items.Remove(item);
      context.SaveChanges();
    }
  }
}

namespace Models
{
  [Table(name: "User")]
  public class User : IKeyedModel
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
  }
}

namespace App
{
  public class UserRepository : IRepository<User> {  /* empty */ }
}
```

Comment: That's nice, but how do you add the dbContext in the service?
services.AddDbContext(?)