# Loose coupling with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, loose-coupling

I'm trying to loosely couple this code, but I'm not sure how or if I should.

I'm using Entity Framework and `DbContext` is the inherited class used by the entity object `TMeasure`. When I run this code I'm getting this error:

> 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' does not contain a definition for 'TMeasures' and no extension method 'TMeasures' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

```
class MeasureRepository: IMeasureRepository
{
    private DbContext db;

    public MeasureRepository(DbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public List<TMeasure> GetAll()
    {
        var results = (from i in db.TMeasures
                        orderby i.strMeasure
                        select i).ToList();
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see in what way this could be considered "loosely coupled", it just seems broken.  What is your end goal here? Do you want to write a repo that work with any DbContext rather than a specific class that derives from DbContext. If so google for "generic repository", i Know I have posted an example in the past.

Comment: Mati (below) gave me a solution to my problem.  It was obviously broken, but I'm talking about not having to instantiate a Entity class within the class.  I'd rather pass the entity object to the class itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your own context:

```
//Internal class recommended
public class MeasuringContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Measure> Measures { get; set; }
}
```

And then use this context instead of the generic one:

```
class MeasureRepository : IMeasureRepository
{
    private MeasuringContext db;

    //...
}
```

Comment: I guess this will allow me to change the context that the MeasureRepository class is receiving, if needed in the future?

Comment: If what you want is a generic context, then this question may be helpful: [Generic access to DbContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151143/generic-access-to-dbcontext)